# Does Bluetooth LE stack supports A2DP profile?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy

Does Bluetooth LE stack supports A2DP profile (audio steaming)? or if there is any dual mode stack which I could use in combination with BLE and classic stack.
Also any information on the hardware which supports this would be great help. Also if anyone knows Android OS supports dual stack?

Comment: BLE has no profiles *at all*, it is the bare protocol. The idea of BLE is that you implement whatever you need on top of that, to reduce nonspecific overhead. BLE is not efficient at dealing with continuous data streams, you are better off using classic bluetooth with A2DP for that. Also see this question: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/100871/streaming-video-using-ble-or-classic-bluetooth-4-0/100879#100879

Answer (score 3):

> Does Bluetooth LE stack supports A2DP profile (audio steaming)?

No, that is part of the classic spec only.

> if there is any dual mode stack which I could use in combination with BLE and classic stack

Probably, none come to mind though because I haven't researched dual-mode chips much.

> Also if anyone knows Android OS supports dual stack?

Generally yes if it has the silicon for it and you are on Android 4.3 or newer. My HTC One has had SDK-supported BLE as well as classic since Android 4.3.

Comment: Is there an extra "not" in the first part of your answer?

Answer (score 0):

The Bluetopia stack from Stonestreet One along with the CC256x from TI can be used for dual mode applications. It is practically the only dual mode bluetooth solution available for those who are not OEMs selling millions. We've used this parts to design with customers and they're quite good.